# python2.7 mysql arabic character show like \xd9\x88\xd9\x88\xd8\xac\xd8\xaf \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\

Tags: python, mysql, encode, arabic

I have a problem when I get my script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
import chardet
import time
start_time = time.time()
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.converters as conv
import MySQLdb.constants as const
import datetime
# connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="985632", use_unicode=True, passwd="azerty",
db="bog_ch" , charset='utf8', init_command='SET NAMES UTF8')
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL select statement
query = "SELECT * FROM articles Limit 5"
cursor.execute(query)
a = []
# commit your changes
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
rows = [x for x in cursor ]
for i in rows:
    for b in i:
        a.append(b)
print a
```

and I get this

```
</span></p>\r\n<p class="a" style="text-align: right;" dir="RTL"><span style="font-size: 21px;" lang="AR-SY">\u0648\u0648\u062c\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0627\u062d\u062b\u0627\u0646 \u0623\u0646 &ldquo;\u0641\u0627\u064a\u0628\u0631&rdquo; \u062a\u0642\u0648\u0645 \u0628\u062a\u062e\u0632\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u064a\u0627\u0646\u0627\u062a \u0641\u064a \u062e\u0648\u0627\u062f\u0645\u0647\u0627 \u0644\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0623\u0633\u0628\u0648\u0639 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0642\u0644. \u0648\u0623\u0636\u0627\u0641 \u0623\u062d\u062f\u0647\u0645\u0627 \u0623\u0646\u0647 \u0644\u0627 \u064a\u0648\u062c\u062f \u0623\u0633\u0644\u0648\u0628 \u0645\u0635\u0627\u062f\u0642\u0629 \u0645\u0633\u062a\u062e\u062f\u0645\u060c \u0645\u0627 \u064a\u0639\u0646\u064a \u0623\u0646 \u0628\u0625\u0645\u0643\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u0645\u064a\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0635\u0648\u0644 \u0625\u0644\u0649 \u0647\u0630\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0648\u0627\u0628\u0637 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0631 \u0625\u0644\u0649 \u062a\u0644\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u064a\u0627\u0646\u0627\u062a \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062d\u0635\u0648\u0644 \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0647\u0627 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0642\u064a\u0627\u0645 \u0628\u0645\u0627 \u064a\u0634\u0627\u0621.</span></p>', u'1', u'', None, datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 9, 0, 36, 30), 9L, 0L, 0L, 1L, u'viber.png', u'User GEEKS', 1L, u'', u'', u'']
```

i want to convert it to arabic like

أفضل المهووسين  ايفون سامسونغ غوغل    7

Answer (score 2):

You're printing the list `a`. This isn't going to work, and in any case you probably didn't want to output all that additional crud to your web page (`9L, 0L, 0L, 1L, u'viber.png',` ...etc...)

If you want the actual Unicode characters to appear, just print the string elements.

For example:

```
>>> my_list = [u'\u0648\u0648\u062c\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0627' \
               u'\u062d\u062b\u0627\u0646', 123]
>>> print my_list        # <- this won't work
[u'\u0648\u0648\u062c\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0627\u062d\u062b\u0627\u0646', 123]
>>> print my_list[0]     # <- but this will
ووجد الباحثان
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Unicode display issue. First, make sure the IDE you are using supports Arabic characters (the best as far as I know is Spyder). Secondly, try this in Python 3.5, it handles Unicode much more effectively.